# Broadleaf commerce customer <=> user setup

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I'm doing a technical analysis on broadleaf and I'm confused on the customer setup. When looking at the [Customer Detail diagram](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/5.0/database-model/customer-model/customer-detail), I don't see the concept of a customer with multiple users. Is this also the case for the B2B setup? Or is there a different structure there, where you have one customer record, and other user records with different roles? 
Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction !
Kind Regards, Marieke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadleaf has a commercial `Account` module for B2B use cases. I believe this module fits the need you describe for multiple B2B users and roles. Here's a descriptive snippet from that module's readme file:

> The account module adds the ability to create and manage organizational accounts for your business. The model supports both Master and Sub-Accounts as well as supporting several role types at each level. The module also provides the ability to have an order go through an order approval workflow based on certain
>   criteria such as your role and whether or not the order qualifies for being approved. One such qualification included out-of-box is the ability to create order approval limits. So, if an order meets the order total threshold, it can automatically be submitted into the order approval workflow. This module also has a dependency on Price Lists which gives it the ability to create `Contract` based price lists that are tied to a specific account.